# Adding a new column with nextval to an existing SNOWFLAKE database table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, nextval

I am trying to insert a new column to an existing table in snowflake with nextval as similar to the supplierID in the below code **(I did get_ddl on my stagingtable to get the below code)**. I added a new sequence and cloned with supplierID and when i did get ddl on the same table, its just showing contactID.nextval but not something like **NUMBER(38,0) DEFAULT CLINIFYQA."ClinifyDB".ORGANIZATIONTYPEID.NEXTVAL**.

Is it still correct or am I doing something wrong.

```
create or replace TABLE stagingtable (
    
    ORGANIZATIONID VARCHAR(200),
    COMPANYID VARCHAR(200),
    SUPPLIERID NUMBER(38,0) DEFAULT CLINIFYQA."ClinifyDB".ORGANIZATIONTYPEID.NEXTVAL)
```

Could someone please advice.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE stagingtable ADD COLUMN newColumn number DEFAULT CLINIFYQA."ClinifyDB".ORGANIZATIONTYPEID.NEXTVAL;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html